# How to put cache on shared memory in Java for two different instances

Tags: java, ehcache

I am using ehcache in my application. I want to put cache on shared memory so any other application(instance) can get cache from shared location.

So can you please help me on that? can you provide some sample code?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try looking into `memcache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at distributed cache solutions.
But for Ehcache this is not free:
http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemorymax

But there are many other distributed cache solutions.
Have a look at Infinispan http://infinispan.org/